# Xcode can't archive project with cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, linker, cocoapods

I have problem with creating Archive of my project. When I try build and run project on devices it's working okay. But when I tried to archive project for distribution I have problem. It takes some time and it's doing all work but at the end I gives me error:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-[project]-ZXingObjC
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
    pod 'ZXingObjC'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
end


target '[project]' do
    shared_pods
end

target '[project]Tests' do

end

target '[project]Demo' do
    shared_pods
end
```

What I've tried:

- Restart Xcode
- Restart OSX
- Remove and add Cocoapods
- Check settings for Build Active Architecture Only (it's same for my project and Pods project)
- Check Build Setting > Other Linker Flag
- Change scheme for Archive from Release to Debug
- Try archive with iOS Device or two real devices
- Disable paralelize builds in Scheme -> Build
- Check http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html
- Project settings -> Info tab –> Configuration sets

and maybe more. I've tried to search questions here and tried google but for now nothing help. I am now downloading Xcode 7 but I don't think it help. So where could be problem? Why it's not archiving project? Thanks for any help or idea

Comment: did you ever resolve the issue ?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure which solution helps. I think some combination of reinstalling Cocoapods, removing Derived data and clearing other build stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today, and the problem is in `use_frameworks`!. Remove it and you'll be able to archive your project.

But you could run into other problem, if your pods have some namespace conflicts.

Answer (score -4):

Archive button is only available when you build on real device. Try it on a real device instead of simulating it.

Comment: Nope, I could Archive even without real device. I could use iOS Device if not real device connected. But I tried real devices too. I tried iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 and same result.

Comment: You can archive without real device.